# Mysql/PHP User customizable background?

Tags: php

I'm a newbie to stack overflow, and let me just say this: it's my new favorite website.
Anyway, here's my question. I know this will have something to do with inserting a picture into a mysql db, but anywhere, here's my question. I have a login/signup system in my website. I would I be able to let the user edit the background picture of the website for their account? (like twitter).

Som variables I have set in header.php

```
    include ( 'mysql_connectinc.php' );
include ( 'functions.php');
function sec_session_start() {
            $session_name = 'username'; // Set a custom session name
            $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
            $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
            $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
            session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
            session_name($username); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
            session_start(); // Start the php session
            session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
        }
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = 'profile';
```

Thanks.
(could u explain how to let the user be able to attatch a picture, store it into a mysql db, retrieve the picture from the db, then set it as the background image? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! I'm afraid questions of the *I-need-some-code-can-you-please-write-it-for-me* sort aren't really considered on-topic here (we'd prefer questions more along the lines of *I-wrote-this-code-but-it's-not-doing-what-I-expected*). But don't despair. Have a stab at implementing this feature yourself, and if you have a specific problem with your code, come back and ask for help. (Incidentally, it's not always a good idea to store images in the database. Just upload it somewhere and store the URL instead.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try figuring it out thanks a bunch!